# Ag-grid trigger events from outside

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, jquery-events

I am working with ag-grid. I have event handlers defined in my `gridOptions`:

```
gridOptions = 
{
...
onCellEditingStarted: function (event) { /* magic happens!*/ },
onCellEditingStopped: function (event) { /* magic happens!*/  }
...
}
```

When cell editing starts/stops - everything works great. But at some point I need to trigger these events from other .js file, where I don't even have ag-grid instance.

I'm trying something like this:

```
$(window).trigger('cellEditingStopped');
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to trigger events for ag-grid in this way or I need some more code to write?

Comment: you need to attach object reference so that you can access the grid from other JS file.

Comment: Yeah, without reference it is not possible to trigger event. I've found solution to my problem. Will write answer later for other users

Comment: yep even i am also doing the same way since there are multiple JS files in which I am manipulating chart data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution i've found to achieve my goal:

```
gridOptions = 
{
...
onCellEditingStarted: function (event) { /* magic happens!*/ },
onCellEditingStopped: function (event) { /* magic happens!*/  }
onGridReady: function() {
                $('#gridContainer').off("cell-editing-stop");
                $('#gridContainer').on("cell-editing-stop", function () {
                    gridOptions.api.stopEditing();
                });
            },
...
}
```

So in my other file i can do something like this:

```
that.OnCellEditingStop = new Event('cell-editing-stop');
$('#gridContainer').trigger('cell-editing-stop');
```

This solution looks clean for me and i don't have to move my grid instance to another file somehow. Hope it will help others somehow